# How is age classified as a categorical variable?

Tags: python, r, categorical-data, binning

O.K this question is very basic, but i can't get it so  need your help.
I understand the idea of splitting age to categories.
For example :
[image: good graph (:]

I don't understand how the model knows that the 30< category is before the 31-45 category, why the 31-45 category is before the 46-60 category and etc. how the model knows not to make this graph -
[image: bad graph ):]

Thanks!

Comment: you need to have age classes as a factor - that lets you specify the order

Comment: when plotting you give the model the sequence of age categories, model does not need them in other areas

Comment: The age intervals are an ordinal variable. In R, these can be represented by an `ordered` factor. Typically, these are included in a model using dummy encoding with polynomial contrasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
age = 1:100

fctr <- as.factor(cut(age, breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100)))

print(levels(fctr))

[1] "(0,25]"   "(25,50]"  "(50,75]"  "(75,100]"
```

There you can see, how the levels are ordered. This is the order that plot and ggplot2 will use. You can change this order in the following way:

```
fctr2 <- factor(fctr,levels(fctr)[c(2,1,3,4)])

print(levels(fctr2))

[1] "(25,50]"  "(0,25]"   "(50,75]"  "(75,100]"
```

If you are working more often with factors consider using the [forcats](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/) package.